# How much slower does Java code with debugging info enabled run?

Tags: java

I am wondering how much of a performance penalty there is if all the Java code I generated had debug information in it. If there is not much of a penalty then I could do things like get very useful information in production when needed without having to recompile.

Comment: @Bart Kiers - hint = different story

Comment: @Andreas_D, the hint might be useful in this context. The OP has to recompile his code to generate debug information. With a logger like Log4j, slf4j or jul, it is a configuration exercise in production.

Comment: @Andreas_D, you're sure? Are you and Zubair the same? :) Sure, I could be wrong, but so could you. I think my hint could be helpful in this case (with an emphasis on 'think').

Comment: Do you mean, is Andreas_D and Zubair the same person with two accounts?

Comment: @Bart Kiers - I definitly don't waste reputation points by logging in with two different accounts ;) But "logging" is not mentioned at all in the question. And "debug information" is a compiler option.

Comment: @Zubair - are we the same? I mean, should know, right?

Comment: O-oh, he's starting to talk to himself! :)

Comment: @Andreas_D, you don't need to log to a file, you could log to the [console](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/ConsoleHandler.html). Sorry, I am not familiar with the "debug information" compiler option (will Google it in a minute).

Comment: @Bart Kiers - have a look at my answer, updated it with some javac details.

Comment: For all those who are interested, yes, me (Zubair) and Andreas_D ARE the same person ;)

Comment: @Zubair - hey, stop that, people may start believing, that this is true ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that you think about line numbers and local variable names.

Both *debug additions* don't add extra instructions to the byte code. So the performance should be unaffected. Line numbers and variable names are just extra tables in the class files and are ignored unless you actually debug the code.

---

[javac compiler options:](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html)

```
-g
    Generate all debugging information, including local variables. 
    By default, only line number and source file information is generated.

-g:none
    Do not generate any debugging information.

-g:{keyword list}
    Generate only some kinds of debugging information, specified by 
    a comma separated list of keywords. Valid keywords are:

    source
        Source file debugging information 
    lines
        Line number debugging information 
    vars
        Local variable debugging information
```

Answer (score 3):

I would *never* debug on any production environment. If you have a problem on prod you need to try and recreate it on a dev or test environment, this is where you might debug. I guess that you've already turned all your logging up to it's highest granularity and this has failed to reveal the problem?

Comment: When you say "debug", how do you define it? Do you mean stepping through a debugger or do you mean instrumentation?

Comment: @Zubair I'm talking about doing anything with the JPDA.

Comment: Yes, logging is turned up to highest granularity but a lot of logging simply isn't there.

Comment: I wouldn't debug on PROD, but there are times when I want the debugging information there, whether it's for logging (line numbers in exceptions, for instance) or for reflection (parameter names being retained)

Comment: I wouldn't run the debugger on a production environment. But I *do* often look at stack traces in production logs. So, in order to see informative logging, you need to include debugging info in the class files.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you're debugging. If you're printing information to console or file, then it will definitely take up some performance. If you're using the Logging API, then maybe you can reduce the granularity as mentioned by Qwerky and that should help.